# fetch a result of an alias in a query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

i have the following query:

```
$timecheck = $db->query("SELECT (B <= NOW()) AS var FROM table1 WHERE x='$x'");          
            while ($row = $db->fetch_object()){ 
                if ($row->var != 0){
                        $updatestatus = $db->query("UPDATE table2 SET abc='1' WHERE x='$x'");
                    }
            }
```

and get the following errormessage:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_object()
```

that relates to this line:

```
while ($row = $db->fetch_object()){
```

i also was trying to use:

```
while ($row = $db->fetch_object($timecheck)){
```

without any success. So in the manual is nothing written about how to use an alias by fetch-method.

it would be great if there is someone who could tell me what am i doing wrong. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`Mysqli::query` does not have `fetch_object` method it would return `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc` for more information please look at

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Example :

```
$result = $db->query ( "SELECT (B <= NOW()) AS var FROM table1 WHERE x='$x'" );
while ( $row = $result->fetch_object () ) {
    if ($row->var != 0) {
        $updatestatus = $db->query ( "UPDATE table2 SET abc='1' WHERE x='$x'" );
    }
}
```

Thanks

:)

Comment: yes. thats it. you saved my day :) would like to upvote but i have not enough reputations :)

Comment: All you need to do is just accept  ... you can still do that even if you don't have reputation

Comment: ah sorry, i forget to say $db is mysqli

Comment: its ok .. i instantly knew it was mysqli ... one more thing accept button is below the reputation arrow

Comment: i know, i just had to wait 3min ... curious about that is, that it works with mysqli?

Comment: Don't worry .. as use PHP .. you would be able to run and debug scripts without running it

Comment: i dont understand why this works when: while ($row = $timecheck->fetch_object()){  means that $timecheck is = mysqli(or $db)_query("...");